# How to export pd.DataFrame into pdf meanwhile keeping its format displayed in ipynb

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Export pd.DataFrame into pdf meanwhile keeping its format displayed in ipynb cell's output.

So I have been trying to do this for a while.
I have tried several suggestions, the HTML one I was having trouble with weasyprint.
Or the nbconvert to convert the whole iplynb to pdf; however, even after I pip install the pandoc, it says that "nbconvert.utils.pandoc.PandocMissing: Pandoc wasn't found.".

Anyone has any more suggestions or advises? Btw, I was running the job on a remote ssh server.